# how to put question marks randomly on one picture?

Tags: graphics

I want to put several question marks on one picture in random sizes and random rotating angles, I can't do that, any suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{picture}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
    \usepackage[first=1,last=1000]{lcg}
    \usepackage{calc} 
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{librarys}
    \def\wordlist{\textquestiondown,\textquestiondown,\textquestiondown,\textquestiondown,\textquestiondown}
      \makeatletter                        
    \newlength{\randx} \newlength{\randy} % Coordinates of the next word should be saved as random generator produces one number
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
      \@for\TempVar:=\wordlist\do{%
        \rand \setlength{\randx}{\paperwidth*\ratio{\value{rand}mm}{1000mm}}  % Set random x position
        \rand \setlength{\randy}{\paperheight*\ratio{\value{rand}mm}{1000mm}} % Set random y position
        \rand  % Generate new random to use as angle
        \put(\randx,\randy){\makebox(0,0)[c]{\rotatebox{\value{rand}}{\TempVar}}}% Show next word
      }
    } 



    \end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say here. Could you please edit your post with proper English?

Comment: I am not sure if I have expressed my idea clearly this time. @Artillect

Comment: @dozer Why this big cyan disc? If you replace `\includegraphics{librarys}` by `\null` (or any correct content), your MWE works...

Comment: It would probably be better to do this in tikz. One problem here is that you are adding the punctuation marks in the background, while the image is in the foreground (but perhaps this was intentional?)

Comment: @daleif Could you give me any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using tikz. Note that because remember picture caches things, you may need to delete the aux file to force it to reposition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[blue] (0,0) circle (5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  % I'll just use letters
  \foreach \letter in {A,B,C,D,E}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\randA{random()}
    \coordinate (A) at ($(current page.north west)!\randA!(current page.north east)$);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\randB{random()}
    \coordinate (B) at ($(current page.north west)!\randB!(current page.south west)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A |- B)$);
    \typeout{A: \randA; B: \randB} 
    \node at (C) {\Huge \letter};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can we limit the positions of letters into the circle? What should I do if I want to put some small pictures randomly into the circle?

Comment: You should probably write another question for that. To get random coordinates inside the circle, you could just use polar coordinates with a random radius between 0 and R and a random angle. For the pictures, A,B,... can be macros. I;m not going to do it all for you, better if you experiment so you get a fell with how this works and what you can find in the tikz manual and by searching for tikz related stuff in google.